# Postgresql : select distinct * from func() ;

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct, postgresql-11

```
----------------     PostgreSQL:    ---------------------

drop table if exists test;
CREATE TABLE test
(
"Id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
"User" VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
"Name" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
"DId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY("User"));
----------------- CREATE  TABLE ---------------------


truncate table test;

insert into test values
(1655,'1000000000','1000000000',6),
(844,'111','111',6),
(847,'114','114',6),
(849,'116','116',6),
(864,'131','131',6),
(884,'151','151',6),
(3242,'201919-11:29:3:340','sizhanerLD',6),
(3241,'201919-11:28:17:506','sizhanerZB',6),
(3240,'201919-11:27:37:15','sizhanerLD',6),
(3239,'201919-11:25:57:629','sizhanerZB',6);
----------------- INSERT  DATA ----------------------

create TYPE "public"."BPI" as (
        "Id" integer,
        "DId"   integer,
        "User"  VARCHAR(64), 
        "Name"  VARCHAR(50) 
);

---------------------------------CREATE TYPE --------------------------------------------------




--------------CREATE 3 FUNC()-----------------

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "QBP_1"()
RETURNS TABLE("Item" "BPI")
AS $$
declare
    "MyCsr" refcursor;
     "SqlStr" varchar(10240) := 'SELECT "Id", "DId", "User", "Name" from test ORDER BY "Name" ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0';
BEGIN
    raise notice 'SQL :%', "SqlStr";
    open "MyCsr" for EXECUTE "SqlStr";   
     fetch "MyCsr" into "Item";
     while FOUND loop
        return next;
        fetch "MyCsr" into "Item";
     end loop;
     close "MyCsr";
     return ;
--select distinct * from "QBP_1"();
END;
$$ language plpgsql;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "QBP_2"()
RETURNS TABLE("Id" integer,
                "DId"   integer,
                "User"  VARCHAR(64), 
                "Name"  VARCHAR(64) )
AS $$
declare
    "MyCsr" refcursor;
     "SqlStr" varchar(10240) := 'SELECT "Id", "DId", "User", "Name" from test ORDER BY "Name" ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0';
BEGIN
    raise notice 'SQL :%', "SqlStr";
    return query execute "SqlStr";
--select distinct * from "QBP_2"();
END;
$$ language plpgsql;


---------------------------------------------------------------


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "QBP_3"()
RETURNS SETOF  "BPI"
AS $$
declare
    "Item"  "BPI";
     "SqlStr" varchar(10240) := 'SELECT "Id", "DId", "User", "Name" from test ORDER BY "Name" ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0';
BEGIN
    raise notice 'SQL :%', "SqlStr";
    for "Item" in execute "SqlStr" LOOP
        return next "Item";
    end LOOP;
--select distinct * from "QBP_3"();
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

SQL1:    `select distinct * from "QBP_1"();`

SQL2:    `select distinct * from "QBP_2"();`

SQL3:    `select distinct * from "QBP_3"();`

SQL4:    `SELECT distinct "Id", "DId", "User", "Name" from test ORDER BY "Name" ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;`

```
returning:

postgres=# select distinct * from "QBP_1"();
NOTICE:  SQL :SELECT "Id", "DId", "User", "Name" from test ORDER BY "Name" ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
  Id  | DId |        User         |    Name
------+-----+---------------------+------------
  844 |   6 | 111                 | 111
 3242 |   6 | 201919-11:29:3:340  | sizhanerLD
  884 |   6 | 151                 | 151
  864 |   6 | 131                 | 131
  847 |   6 | 114                 | 114
  849 |   6 | 116                 | 116
 3241 |   6 | 201919-11:28:17:506 | sizhanerZB
 3239 |   6 | 201919-11:25:57:629 | sizhanerZB
 3240 |   6 | 201919-11:27:37:15  | sizhanerLD
 1655 |   6 | 1000000000          | 1000000000
(10 rows)

postgres=# select distinct * from "QBP_2"();
NOTICE:  SQL :SELECT "Id", "DId", "User", "Name" from test ORDER BY "Name" ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
  Id  | DId |        User         |    Name
------+-----+---------------------+------------
  844 |   6 | 111                 | 111
 3242 |   6 | 201919-11:29:3:340  | sizhanerLD
  884 |   6 | 151                 | 151
  864 |   6 | 131                 | 131
  847 |   6 | 114                 | 114
  849 |   6 | 116                 | 116
 3241 |   6 | 201919-11:28:17:506 | sizhanerZB
 3239 |   6 | 201919-11:25:57:629 | sizhanerZB
 3240 |   6 | 201919-11:27:37:15  | sizhanerLD
 1655 |   6 | 1000000000          | 1000000000
(10 rows)

postgres=# select distinct * from "QBP_3"();
NOTICE:  SQL :SELECT "Id", "DId", "User", "Name" from test ORDER BY "Name" ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
  Id  | DId |        User         |    Name
------+-----+---------------------+------------
  844 |   6 | 111                 | 111
 3242 |   6 | 201919-11:29:3:340  | sizhanerLD
  884 |   6 | 151                 | 151
  864 |   6 | 131                 | 131
  847 |   6 | 114                 | 114
  849 |   6 | 116                 | 116
 3241 |   6 | 201919-11:28:17:506 | sizhanerZB
 3239 |   6 | 201919-11:25:57:629 | sizhanerZB
 3240 |   6 | 201919-11:27:37:15  | sizhanerLD
 1655 |   6 | 1000000000          | 1000000000
(10 rows)

postgres=# SELECT distinct "Id", "DId", "User", "Name" from test ORDER BY "Name" ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
  Id  | DId |        User         |    Name
------+-----+---------------------+------------
 1655 |   6 | 1000000000          | 1000000000
  844 |   6 | 111                 | 111
  847 |   6 | 114                 | 114
  849 |   6 | 116                 | 116
  864 |   6 | 131                 | 131
  884 |   6 | 151                 | 151
 3242 |   6 | 201919-11:29:3:340  | sizhanerLD
 3240 |   6 | 201919-11:27:37:15  | sizhanerLD
 3241 |   6 | 201919-11:28:17:506 | sizhanerZB
 3239 |   6 | 201919-11:25:57:629 | sizhanerZB
(10 rows)
```

As shown in the code above. I create 3 functions for a simple test. But it seems that SQL 123 returns a wrong order.  (If I remove "distinct", the returning is in the correct order)  Did I use "distinct" incorrectly?   And Why?

At last, I apologize for my pooooooooooooooooooooooor English. Hope it doesn't affect your reading

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but your use of cursors and dynamic SQL is complete overkill. You don't need PL/pgSQL, loops or dynamic SQL to return the result of a query.

Comment: You should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables in a relational database represent relations. Relations are a special type of (multi) sets. And sets have no order. So the result of a query in SQL can be in any order unless the **outermost** query explicitly orders the result with an `ORDER BY` clause.

Of course there somehow is a physical order of a result when outputted. But the important point is, that the engine can return the result in any order when the `ORDER BY` clause is missing. In your case the engine might process the intermediate result from the function in a way "good" for the depuplication (`DISTINCT`), and that can "reorder" the tuples (possibly even in another order each time the query is issued).

If you want an ordered result include an `ORDER BY` clause in the outermost query like in

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       *
       FROM "QBP_1"()
       ORDER BY "Name";
```

and analog for the other functions. Otherwise you cannot expect a certain order, i.e. there's also no "wrong order" then.

And as a side note: Consider not to use this camel case identifiers that always require quoting. That can be very confusing. Just going with unquoted (lower case) identifiers can save some trouble.

Comment: I misunderstand “distinct”。Thank you very much for your reply。

Comment: To extend @sticky bit a little. Postgres is case insensitive to not double quoted identifiers. So if you really want to use CamelCase without double quoting you can. Just realize that anytime Postgres reports it back it'll be lowered cased. So fore example Name becomes name.